# How Dispose Method can be call when I use SqlConnection Object?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose

I just code in .NET so when i readed about **Using** statement. It's can be understand like try-finally below. Can anyone explain for me what is **((IDisposable)connection).Dispose()** and Why have to spetific **(IDisposable)** before Name variable if i want to use Dispose()?

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(AddressBox.Text.Trim()))
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
```

Same this:

```
try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(AddressBox.Text.Trim());
            connection.Open();
        }
        finally
        {
            ((IDisposable)connection).Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: `SqlConnection` implements `IDisposable` by default so the cast to it is unnecessary. Just using `connection.Dispose()` is sufficient if you wanted to (for some reason) use the try/finally methodology.

Comment: @MarcusParsons Where can i read aout SqlConnection implement IDisposable by default? I very need it to understand anything about dispose(). Some where on MSDN talk about that but not clear with me. Please help me understand

Comment: [`SqlConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) inherits from [`DbConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), which implements `IDisposable`

Answer (score 1):

`IDisposable` is an interface to implement dispose mechanism for C# objects. For e.g, reading a file from filesystem needs a read stream to be opened, once all reading is done, then the stream must be disposed. SQL connection is opened, then performed some SQL db operations, finally the opened connection need to be closed.

`IDisposable` interface is useful for such Dispose method, where the resources are released.

The `using` block automatically calls the `Dispose` method, once the block execution has been finished. Without using block developer need to take care of calling `Dispose` once the work is done.

To check about IDisposable, try creating a class which implements IDisposable interface.

Comment: I can call SqlConnection.Dispose() without implements IDisposable. So why can i do that? I tried to find how SqlConnection.Dispose() can call by default and who objects have Dispose() method by default? Unmanaged Resources?

Comment: It's all about how a developer choose to write code. `using` block handles the call of disposing automatically, other way is the developer may call `Dispose` method manually.

Comment: Here is a good place to learn about the IDisposable documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-5.0